# An error occurred building visual studio cordova app using multi-device-hybrid-apps only in Release and Distribution configuration

Tags: android, cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am developing a mobile app using Cordova by multi-device-hybrid-apps in Visual Studio 2013,
Everything is fine on Debug configuration, the app will compile correctly and is installed on the device. But when I try to compile and deploy via Release or Distribution configuration it will give me this error

```
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,release,-f,d:\PhoneGap\projects\MyWeddingCard\MyWeddingCard\bld\Distribution\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
1>  Command finished with error code 2: d:\phonegap\projects\MyWeddingCard\MyWeddingCard\bld\Distribution\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --release,
1>  
1>  C:\Users\RezaRa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\q\q.js:126
1>                      throw e;
1>                            ^
1>EXEC : error : d:\phonegap\projects\MyWeddingCard\MyWeddingCard\bld\Distribution\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2
1>      at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\RezaRa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
1>      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
1>      at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
1>      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

I know this a general error but is there any way to undrestand what is the problem.

p.s I have created Keystore file and added to ant.properties file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem I changed keystore file path in ant properties from

`key.store=D:\PhoneGap\projects\MyWeddingCard\Key\MyWeddingCardKeystore.keystore`

to

`key.store=D:\\PhoneGap\\projects\\MyWeddingCard\\Key\\MyWeddingCardKeystore.keystore`

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this. I had the same issue and couldn't find a solution anywhere. Much appreciated.